# Combine 2 arrays into a multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript

This is based on my last question.

I have these arrays:

```
var array1 = new Array ("Pepsi", "Coke", "Juice", "Water");
var array2 = new Array ("35",    "17",   "21",    "99");
```

And I want to combine them to form a multidimensional array like this:

```
[
    ["Pepsi","35"]
    ["Coke", "17"]
    ["Juice","21"]
    ["Water","99"]
]
```

I tried this script:

```
Values=[];

for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    Values[i] = Array(array1[i], array2[i]);
}
```

But it gave a result like this (correct values, incorrect names):

```
[
    ["a","35"]
    ["c","17"]
    ["E","21"]
    ["I","99"]
]
```

Comment: [**What you have works for me**](http://jsfiddle.net/VdRyr/)

Comment: Your code is [correct](http://jsfiddle.net/xd7Bf/), at least on Firefox and Opera...

Comment: Where would the capital E and I come from, or are those typos?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var array1 = ["Pepsi", "Coke", "Juice", "Water"],
    array2 = ["35", "17", "21", "99"],
    result = [], i = -1;

while ( array1[++i] ) { 
  result.push( [ array1[i], array2[i] ] );
}
```

As written, this solution assumes you will only ever be using strings. As @ajax333221 has pointed out in the comments below, this would cause problems if you were to involve `boolean` or `int` values into this solution. As such, I'd like to propose an improvement that will accomplish your goals, while not tripping over difficult values and types:

```
var array1 = [false, 0, "Juice", -1],
    array2 = ["35", "17", "21", "99"],
    result = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++ ) {
  result.push( [ array1[i], array2[i] ] );
}
```

Comment: you assumed he will always work with strings. If he works with other things like numbers `0` or booleans `false`, there will be problems

Comment: @ajax333221 Yes, I'm assuming the question represents the problem.

Comment: @JonathanSampson And I will now assume you don't like to write maintainable and flexible code

Comment: @ajax333221 I appreciate your advice, and I've added a `for` loop to side-step any issues with types and values of the falsey nature.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `.map()` on Arrays.

```
var Values = array1.map(function(v,i) {
    return [v, array2[i]];
});
```

---

See the [MDN shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility) for older browsers.

***live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/D9rjf/

---

If you're going to do this operation quite a bit, you could make a reusable function.

In this example, I extended `Array.prototype`, but that's not necessary if you don't like that.

```
Array.prototype.combine = function(arr) {
    return this.map(function(v,i) {
        return [v, arr[i]];
    });
};
```

---

```
var Values = array1.combine(array2);
```

***live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/D9rjf/1/

Comment: not enough answers on SO like this using non-destructive methods to create arrays